# Are the edges of a planar graph part of its faces? (Graph Theory)

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

The definition of face I have learned for planar graphs is "a region where any 2 points in it not on $G$ can be connected by a line which doesn't intersect any of the edges of $G$". I am wondering if this region would include the actual edges themselves- as it is vacuously true that points which lie on the edges can be connected by  a line which doesn't intersect the edges (as I would translate the definition as being for any 2 points on the plane in $f$, if they are not in G and can be connected without intersecting an edge, then $f$ is a face of $G$, and for 2 points on $G$, the antecedent of the implication in my translation is false so the statement is vacuously true for these points).

Comment: Define "not on $G$" and you have your answer.

Comment: Usually "vacuously true" means "there's nothing to actually prove", but it's not really obvious that points on edges of a face can be connected.

Comment: That second sentence is a bit difficult for me to parse. Could you break it into smaller ones?